# Can statistics from a certain country be used in another country?

Tags: distributions, inference, population

This is my first time posting a question on a forum-like site, I hope my question is not out-of-topic and I'm writing clearly enough.

So, I came across some tweets about [the distribution of wealth amongst boomers, millennials, and gen-x](https://twitter.com/DanPriceSeattle/status/1392571782155030530) and [wealth per person of people on a certain age ranges](https://twitter.com/jmhorp/status/1393245141876580355). I presume the data was US-based.

My question is: *can these US-based statistics be used to make the **same claims** (or roughly the same, maybe?) about populations and distributions in a different country? More specifically, can I make claims about the same share of wealth and wealth per person in my country based on the US-based statistics?*

Also, it would be helpful if you can include the general rule of thumb of whether or not a certain country's statistics can be used to make claims about another country. Links and references to learn more are also appreciated, thank you so much!

Note on me personally: I've taken and watched some videos about statistics, but still easily confused about many things statistics-related.

Comment: I think this is an easy "No" I am afraid. USA is an outlier in many economic metrics. Maybe using a neighbouring country to your country of interest is more appropriate but large countries like USA, China, India, etc. are pretty unique to serve as exemplars for other countries. If horribly pressed I would use some UN statistics for the overall region of the country of interest.

Comment: Of course you can "make the same claims" -- but you have no basis to defend them.  You could, with equal logical and statistical validity (which means none at all), claim that people have fur, fangs, and tails because dogs do, dogs are mammals, and people are mammals.